# Compare value of datagrid with value selected from database

Tags: datagridview, compare, sqldatareader

I fill the grid with excel data and want to compare if value exists on database or not ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                string strConn = @"Data Source='" + dbconfig.tb1 + "';Initial Catalog='" + dbconfig.tb2 + "';user='" + dbconfig.tb3 + "';pwd='" + dbconfig.tb4 + "'";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CODE FROM LG_" + dbconfig.tb5 + "_TABLE WHERE CODE NOT LIKE '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "'", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Check ITEMS" + reader[i].ToString());
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: can u elaborate ur problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to check if record with some value from your grid aleady exists in DB, I suggest you to use ExecuteScalar method:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SELECT COUNT (Code) FROM Table WHERE .....);
var res = command.ExecuteScalar();

                    if ((int)res > 0)
                        //Record exists
                    else
                        //record does not exists
```

Comment: Grid Value bmw -mercedes -audi

DB Value --- -mercedes -audi

I want to catch and warn cell "BMW" because BMW does not exists in database

Comment: Collect the values from DGV in list and build correct sql query, something like "SELECT COUNT (Code) where Manufacturer in (your values from DGV ). OR check every DGV row separately: SELECT COUNT (Code) FROM Table WHERE Manufacturer = Value from DGV